# Trigger when video completes in an iframe on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, iframe

I have a video in an `iframe` on a page. I am hoping to trigger a `function`, let's say an `alert("Finished");` when the video finishes.

Hence, there are two things I wanna do:

- Show alert()
- Trigger alert when the video finishes.

The video is in an iframe.

### HTML

```
<div class="h5p-iframe-wrapper">
<iframe id="h5p-iframe-3" class="h5p-iframe h5p-initialized" data-content-id="3" style="height: 761px;" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">

<video src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" preload="metadata" class="h5p-video" style="display: block;"></video>

</iframe></div>
```

### This is what I tried

```
$("iframe").each(function() { 
        var src= $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src',src);  
});
```

It kinda doesn't work.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless the iframe and the page containing it are sitting in the same domain.

Comment: It'd  be so good if you can post a JSfiddle link of your code :)

Comment: Hi Aakash, I wish I could. That page is all jumbled up.

Comment: @Steve You cannot wrap an iframe around another element like that. Anything between `<iframe src='...>` and `</frame>` will not render unless the `<iframe>` is not supported. AFAIK all browsers support `<iframe>` so placing `<video>` tag within the `<frame>` is useless.

Comment: @Steve unless you have a video on the same domain as your webpage, you cannot fully access the video in an `<iframe>`. See [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @Steve One more thing - under 'living' spec, you don't need to define src of an iframe to `about: blank` anymore. And secondly, why are you using an iframe if you just need a video inside the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you going for a video inside an iframe when you don't have anything inside the iframe?

This is just using the `video` tag inside `div`.

```
 $(".h5p-iframe-wrapper > video").on('ended',function(){  alert('Video has ended!');  });
```

or

```
 $("div > video",".h5p-iframe-wrapper").on('ended',function(){  alert('Video has ended!');  });
```

or

```
$(".h5p-iframe-wrapper").contents().find('video').on('ended',function(){ alert("Video has ended!");});
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives some syntax error. Says, Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: I'm sorry, Steve! How about this now?